# Cannot Login to Microsoft Personal Account with Microsoft OAuth v2

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I am trying to integrate Microsoft account login to my ASP.NET Core application. I have setup a microsoft application in the Microsoft Application Registration portal with the given redirect URI.

[image]

Here is a snippet from the Startup.cs file.

```
// Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountOptions()
{
    // I can't post my secrets here
    ClientId = "my_client_id",
    ClientSecret = "my_client_secret"
});
```

When I run the app and login via Microsoft, I get redirected to the Microsoft Login page.

It has the following query parameters (with the id's removed)

```
client_id:my_client_id
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
response_type:code
redirect_uri:https://localhost:44328/signin-microsoft
state:the_state
```

When I sign in with my microsoft personal account, I got redirected to an error page instead.

[image]

The URL says `The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application`

I verified that my redirect URL in the microsoft app is exactly the same as the redirect url passed to the Microsoft log in page so I don't know what's the issue.

Another weird thing though if I log in using a Work or School account, I can proceed properly and it redirects me to the callback page.

Can anyone please help me on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Double check if you are using latest version of authentication middleware in your project (there was few changes few week ago due to changes in MS OAuth - now v2 it's in use).
2. Double check if you have created app under new v2 endpoint - read more here: [How to register an app with the v2.0 endpoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-app-registration/).
3. Double check if you have created password for your app on Microsoft Site.
4. Check `Live SDK support` option in 'Advenced' section - this should be enabled (at least in my case, but look like this doesn't help in your).

Here you can find more information:

- [Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later. (GitHub #827)](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/827)
- [External login via Microsoft Account failed on RC2/RC3 (GitHub #866)](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/827)
- [Enabling authentication using external providers](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html)

**Update:**

Ok, I see now - you have two things:

- missing https (ssl), see [this post](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/866#issuecomment-226965107),
- different port number - it means that is different url and this is reason of your problem - you'r using different url than registered with your app:

`http://localhost:54554/signin-microsoft` - registred in app

`https://localhost:44328/signin-microsoft` - form your error message

Comment: 1. I am using v 1.0.0.0 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount which is the latest version in nugget.
2. I created it using the v2 endpoint https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/
3. I only created an app secret for my app

Question, does v2 work for personal accounts? I found this snippet in the link you provided:

"This means that you can not register an application in your Azure AD tenant using a personal Microsoft account."

although I am not quite sure what it means. Does that mean that I can only create accounts within my own organization?

Comment: I'm using v2 endpoint app, Microsoft Personal account and MVC Core project... everything working fine in my case. However my project is running on my own server, I'm not using Azure, so I'm not sure about Azure AD.

Comment: Did you check 'Live SDK support' option in 'Advenced' section - I'm not sure about this, but I need this enabled in my case.

Comment: I checked the Live SDK support but still no luck. I can only log in with any Work account. I tried 2 work accounts with different domains and they worked. However, when I try any personal account, still encountering the same error. Do you have a sample source code that works that I can try?

Comment: One thing I noticed though when I  type in a personal account such as xxx@outlook.com in other microsoft services , I am being redirected to this URL https://login.live.com/login.srf. I think this is what it's attempting to do as well in my own account and probably has something to do with the error.

Comment: This is funny thing - I don't have any special stuff... I have just add middleware, in startup I have 'app.UseMicrosoftAccount' with 'id' & 'secret' only, and of course I have created app on apps.dev.microsoft.com. That's all...

Comment: I can share my code via GitHub if you want (but I can do it tomorrow) or if you want I can look into your project and test it... Other thing is - can you paste here printscreen from your apps.dev.microsoft.com ?

Comment: Here's the github repo of my code. https://github.com/randalvance/TestApplication1/

Comment: Ok, I see problem - it's https and port number - read my updated answer, please.

Comment: That was actually from a previous project. If you try to create an app with http as well it still doesn't work. If I use https for my project and register https in my app it still doesn't work. I also take note of my ports that they match. Plus if they don't match then work accounts should not work as well. Let me try to register my app later using a plain outlook.com account if it has something to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any more idea - It's should work. It must be some 'detail', but It's hard to guess in general case.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Will probably skip using Microsoft Accounts for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I use Microsoft Oauth 2.0 to solve this problem. You can find MVC .net sample at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/